# page blocked by chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a chrome extension, that will redirect to custom html file. the page is blocked by the browser

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Hello World!",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["src/blocker.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "src/html/popup.html"
    }
}
```

blocker.js

```js
window.location.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("html/popup.html");
```

[Page blocked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA7Ft.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add `blocked.html` to `web_accessible_resources` in `manifest.json` or switch to  using [declarativeRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/)